# Applying a particular rule to a held (or unevaluated) function

Tags: evaluation, hold

I am a very novice Mathematica user and still can't get my head around its evaluation control, all possible constructs related to it (e.g. `Hold`, `Unevaluated`, etc.) and how they work, despite the thorough documentation and the numerous StackExchange and StackOverflow questions discussing this topic. So, apologies for any possible duplicates.

My use case is the following: I have a function (say `f`) defined by thousands of rules and patterns (`DownValues`). I want to start from an unrolled representation of `f[expr]` (for some `expr`) and get the result of applying a single, particular rule to `f[expr]`. I want the result to stay unrolled as well.

As a particular example, suppose we have the following:

```
 In[1]: nat[0] := 0
 In[2]: nat[n_] := 1 + nat[n - 1]
 In[3]: DownValues[nat]
Out[3]: {HoldPattern[nat[0]] :> 0, HoldPattern[nat[n_]] :> 1 + nat[n - 1]}
 In[4]: nat[10]
Out[4]: 10
```

Now, I want to start from an expression represented as `nat[10]` (unevaluated!) and want to specifically apply the second rule (`HoldPattern[nat[n_]] :> 1 + nat[n - 1]`) to obtain the expression in the form of `1 + nat[9]`. Analogously, shall I wish to apply the first rule (`HoldPattern[nat[0]] :> 0`), I would expect the result to stay unchanged in its original form, i.e. `nat[10]`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For very good tutorials on this subject see the notebook at https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/377/  and  Chapter 7 at https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2dsyvptnxjd369/Wagner%20All%20Parts-RC.pdf

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! You might be looking for `HoldForm[nat[10]] /. DownValues[nat][[2]]`. `/.` acts on all parts of the expression, but all of those parts are within a `HoldForm`, so they don't evaluate any further. (Note that `HoldForm` is the same as `Hold`, with the only difference being how it prints in the output cell.) But, this has the unpleasant effect of not evaluating anything else in the expression, e.g. `10 - 1`. To *only* hold occurrences of `nat` in an expression sounds like a good exercise! There are many ways to do that, but if you're stuck I can keep trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider applying specific rules instead of defining your function.

```
ClearAll[nat];
rule1=nat[0]:>0;
rule2=nat[n_]:>1+nat[n-1];
(* The :> will change into a single character as you type. *)
```

Then apply use Replace (/.) with the rule you want to use like this.

```
nat[10]/.rule2
(* 1+nat[9] *)
```

You can do the following to see what happens after applying the rule several times.

```
useRule2[expr_]:=expr/.rule2;
Nest[useRule2,nat[10],4]
(* 4+nat[6] *)
```

However, experienced used do that as follows instead.

```
Nest[#/.rule2&,nat[10],4]
(* 4+nat[6] *)
```

to learn how to use #& read about Function at  http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_A-K_34.html
and  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html?q=Function

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Ted Ersek](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/460/ted-ersek)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/242540/78096), I figured that the following steps work for me so far without having to explicitly convert and rewrite `nat`'s preexisting definitions (as I am working with third-party code where the function of interest is defined by literally thousands of rules).

```
 In[6] rules = DownValues[nat]                                                 
Out[6] {HoldPattern[nat[0]] :> 0, HoldPattern[nat[n_]] :> 1 + nat[n - 1]}

 In[7] DownValues[nat] = {}                                                    
Out[7] {}

 In[8] nat[10]                                                                 
Out[8] nat[10]

 In[9] nat[10] /. rules[[1]]                                                   
Out[9] nat[10]

 In[10] nat[10] /. rules[[2]]                                                  
Out[10] 1 + nat[9]
```